# Not Matching Original Arrray and OpenCV imread Array after imwrite that original Array

Tags: opencv

I have a 3d numpy array, I have saved that array using cv2.imwrite function in form of jpg image, after reading that image I am trying to compare it with original array and found that they are not matching. It also doesn't seems to be RGB or BGR issue.

```
    f1 <- Original Array
    cv2.imwrite("fm1.jpg", f1)
    f1_ = cv2.imread("fm1.jpg")
    print (f1[0][:5])
    print ("---------------------")
    print (f1_[0][:5])
```

```
Output:
[[105 115 150]
 [ 75 121 139]
 [111 116 151]
 [110 118 151]
 [ 94 119 146]]
---------------------
[[ 90 121 144]
 [ 91 116 142]
 [107 118 150]
 [110 116 151]
 [110 115 148]]
```

Comment: use a png, not a lossy format as jpg!

Comment: Yeah Thanks It works!